# warning: statement has no effect (C++)

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
void CScriptTable::EnumReferences(asIScriptEngine *engine)
{
    if (m_table)
    {   
        // Call the gc enum callback for each nested table      
        size_t col = 0, row = 0, num_cols = m_table->numCols(), num_rows = m_table->numRows();

        for( col; col < num_cols; col++ )   // Line 92
        {   
            if (m_table->getColType(col) == COL_TABLE) {
                for (row; row < num_rows; row++){  // Line 95
                    Table * tbl = m_table->getTable(row, col);
                    engine->GCEnumCallback(tbl);
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

When compiling, (g++), the warning (statement has no effect) is issued for line 92 & 95 (indicated in the snippet above)

I can't see why they have no effect even though I have been staring at it for a while - could do with a second pair of eyes to see if they can spot what I'm missing.

Comment: Split up your variable declarations. That line is insane. And why did you declare your loop variables outside the loop anyway? Don’t do that.

Comment: There is a subtle bug in your code. `row` is set at 0 once, before entering the `col` loop, and never reset afterwards. Therefore, on the first iteration of the outer (`col`) loop, you do iterate on the rows, but for all the other iterations, you just do nothing. See @b.buchhold's answer which solve both your original question and this bug... and learn to declare your variables in as tight a scope as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If guess you want to iterate over all columns and for each of them over all rows. so better change your code to something like this:

The first statement in the for loop is executed once, i.e. at the time the loop is entered at first. Since you want to include row number zero for all further columns you have to set row to 0 for each column:

```
void CScriptTable::EnumReferences(asIScriptEngine *engine)
{
    if (m_table)
    {   
        // Call the gc enum callback for each nested table      
        size_t num_cols = m_table->numCols(), num_rows = m_table->numRows();

        for(size_t col = 0; col < num_cols; col++ )   // Line 92
        {   
            if (m_table->getColType(col) == COL_TABLE) {
                for (size_t row = 0; row < num_rows; row++){  // Line 95
                    Table * tbl = m_table->getTable(row, col);
                    engine->GCEnumCallback(tbl);
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's about the `col` and `row` part in the initializer part of the loops. Those statements do nothing. Just remove it:

```
for( ; col < num_cols; col++)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for( col; col < num_cols; col++ )

col;
```

This has no effect. You have to assign something to it, or don't write it at all. Since you assign it out of your loop you just need to leave an empty`;` at that place or use while loops.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting these warnings because the initialization statements in the `for` loops are expressions that does nothing:

```
for(col; col < num_cols; col++)  // line 92: "col" has no effect
for(row; row < num_rows; row++)  // line 95: "row" has no effect
```

Since you've already initialized these variables outside the loop, you might want to omit them from the `for` statement:

```
for(; col < num_cols; col++)  // line 92
for(; row < num_rows; row++)  // line 95
```

However, the best thing to do here is to initialize the variables in the `for` loops themselves rather than outside them:

```
// Call the gc enum callback for each nested table
size_t num_cols = m_table->numCols(), num_rows = m_table->numRows();

for(size_t col = 0; col < num_cols; col++ )   // Line 92
{   
    if (m_table->getColType(col) == COL_TABLE) {
        for (size_t row = 0; row < num_rows; row++){  // Line 95
            Table * tbl = m_table->getTable(row, col);
            engine->GCEnumCallback(tbl);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to type the variable names in your for cycle (as a tip maybe?), try by changing:

```
for( col; col < num_cols; col++ )
```

to something like this:

```
for( col = col; col < num_cols; col++ )
```

for both the lines. It should do the job.

Comment: That has the potential to hide an uninitialized variable warning, or generate a particularly awful "variable initialized with itself" warning. I've even seen that crash a fragile compiler. And it's bad style.

Comment: That error happens when 'col' has not yet been initialized, which is not the case.. I agree with you, it's really bad style, but I'm assuming he knows the right syntax..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you could simply use

```
for(; col < num_cols; col++ )   // Line 92
```

and

```
for (; row < num_rows; row++) {  // Line 95
```